# Realm migration enumerate can not execute

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-access, realm

I am using realm for my iOS project. When I execute migration as doc said,

```
    // Migrtion
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(
        schemaVersion: 1,
        migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
            if oldSchemaVersion < 1 {
                migration.enumerate(WishHistory.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
                    let createdTime = oldObject!["createdTime"] as! NSDate
                    newObject!["satisfiedTime"] = createdTime
                }
            }
    })
```

my app will crash. The error is like below

[image]

It seems that call to `migration.enumerate()` will just crashed.
If I don't call this method, everything is fine except that I have to set my new add property manualy.

**[UPDATE]**

Find a [Same issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2859)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you figured out yourself, this is a [known issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2859) with Realm until the release 0.96.2 and a fix will be shipped with the next version. As a workaround for now, I'd recommend with CocoaPods to build from the head of the master branch, which you can achieve easier by using:

```
 pod 'RealmSwift', :head
 pod 'Realm', :head
```

Note: I'd recommend that you revert that change, after the next release is out and use instead a tagged version again, that makes it easier to figure out issues and keep track of changes and required actions on update.

Answer (score 0):

Like this [issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2859) said modify Podfile to

```
pod 'RealmSwift', :git => 'https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git'
pod 'Realm', :git => 'https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git'
```